# align layout from action bar bottom

Tags: android, layout, alignment, scrollview

I wanna align my layout from the back, home and recent button android on the bottom because the end of my content sits under those buttons. I've used a scroll view with constraint layout in a linear layout that I've attached its codes in the below, I have tried different ways but I couldn't fix it. :/ 
thanks for your help

the back, home, and recent button

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="rtl"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context="test.NewsPageActivity"
  tools:showIn="@layout/activity_news_page">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textDirection="rtl">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleNewsPage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="title"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleNewsPage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNewsPage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this use `RelativeLayout` as parent than use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to add your controlss at the bottom of your Screen like below sample code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add property `android:fillViewport="true"` to `scrollview`.

Otherwise use relative layout and set the `imageview` property `android:layout_alignParentBottom` to `true`..